# Better design for common error handling across methods

Tags: java

I have couple of methods which does same type of error handling and want to refactor it. All methods `X` in my class call `binding.X` where `binding` is my dependency class (third party/Salesforce soap API so we don't have control over type of exception thrown). `X` can be `create`, `update`, `delete`,`query`. For all of these methods, I have to check if exception code is for session expired, then login again and retry the method.

```
public void create(SObject[] s){
try{
    binding.create(s);
 } catch (ApiFault e) {
    if(e.getExceptionCode == INVALID_SESSION_ID) {
               //login again
               login();
       //retry
       binding.create(s);
    }
 }
}
```

Same pattern follows for update, delete. Query method accepts different arguments.

```
public void query(String query){
    try{
        binding.query(query);
    } catch (ApiFault e) {
        if(e.getExceptionCode == INVALID_SESSION_ID) {
            //login again
               login();
           //retry on specific code
           binding.query(query);
        }
    }
}
```

So I have put the logic of retrying on INVALID_SESSION_ID in every method. Is there a better way to design these methods?

Comment: Catching `Exception` is a very bad idea. This also looks like you're using exceptions for control-flow/business-logic and that is also a bad idea.

Comment: In actual code, its more specific exception but still not specific enough that I can retry on exception. I have to check for exception code.

Comment: If you think of using Spring's AOP, you can handle such situation very easily. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

Comment: You're *still* using exceptions for business logic and that's not good at all.

Comment: `binding` is third party (Salesforce soap API) so we don't have control over type of exception thrown. We have to retry in this way or maybe I am not able to think of better way.

Comment: My mistake then. I was under the impression that this was code that was under your control. Are you sure that the Salesforce Soap API doesn't provide you another method to check the state of the query? You also might want to mention in the question that you are using a 3rd-party API.

Comment: Updated question. Salesforce document also mention this. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_concepts_errorhandling.htm

Comment: @nachokk, updated question with actual exception. http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/force/api/force-partner-api/22.0.0/force-partner-api-22.0.0-javadoc.jar!/com/sforce/soap/partner/fault/ApiFault.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could wrap every operation into a strategy:

```
private void executeWithLogin(Runnable r) {
    try {
        r.run();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        if (e.getExceptionCode == INVALID_SESSION_ID) {
            //login again
            login();
            //retry on specific code
            r.run();
        }
    }
}

public void create(final SObject[] s){
    executeWithLogin(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            binding.create(s);
        }
    });
}

// same for other operations
```

You're forced to use verbose anonymous classes do do that, but Java 8 will make that much more readable and less verbose with lambdas:

```
public void create(SObject[] s){
    executeWithLogin(() -> binding.create(s));
}
```

Comment: Looks good. Quick question, if binding.create throws any checked exception, I would have to rethrow them as `RuntimeException` since we are creating `Runnable`?

Comment: No. You can just use another interface than Runnable, whose method throws the checked exception to be caught in executeWithLogin(). Something like `interface Action { void execute() throws Exception }`. Or simply use a `Callable<Void>`.

Comment: Defining own interface seems reasonable. Approach sounds perfect.

Comment: @nachokk: if the signature perfectly matches, I don't see why it would be tricky. A Runnable is an operation to be run, and it fits perfectly with what the OP wants to do (unless the binding operations throw a checked exception). But if you feel a dedicated interface makes things more redable, then go with it, no problem.

Comment: throws `ApiFault` but don't know if is checked or unchecked